# What techniques can be used to buff a stainless steel sink?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, sink

Hypothetically, say I was too aggressive using a bucket in a new stainless steel sink.

Hypothetically, say the sink now has some scratches.

I used an oxalic acid based cleanser ([Bar Keepers Friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_Keepers_Friend)), scrubbing in the direction of the grain.  Sink cleaned up nicely, but the scratches were barely dented (scratched).

How is the grain originally put into the sink?  I would assume a wire wheel.  I would think metal buffing compound would make the surface TOO smooth.

Any tips or techniques would be appreciated.

Comment: I use Cerama Bryte on glass stove and sink, not high sheen but it is basically a cleaning wax. Gets the job done for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "grain" is a result of a 25 minute grinding and buffing process completed near the end of the creation of the sink.

This video gives a bit of a clue.  The final stages are at the 3:50 mark.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYd7-ZNbg5g

Comment: Very interesting!  I found a video on the same page from ProLine Range hoods that uses maroon and grey scotchbrite pads for scratch removal, a bit more accessable from the custom die grinders the factory uses: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOmUran35dE

Answer (score 2):

Per the [video at ProLine Range](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOmUran35dE), ScotchBrite pads should be wrapped around a block of wood, for even pressure.  The 'sanding stroke' should go in ***one direction only***, parallel with the grain, lifting for the return stroke.  They recommended starting with the maroon (320-400) and then progress to the light grey (600-800).  I started and ended with the green, so I'll go back and try again.

SCOTCHBRITE GRIT CHART

7445 - White pad, called Light Duty Cleansing - (1000)

7448 - Light Grey, called Ultra Fine Hand - (600-800)

6448 - Green, called Light Duty Hand Pad - (600)

7447 - Maroon pad, called General Purpose Hand - (320-400)

6444 - Brown pad, called Extra Duty Hand - (280-320)

7446 - Dark Grey pad, called Blending Pad (180-220)

7440 - Tan pad, called Heavy Duty Hand Pad - (120-150)

Answer (score 1):

Anytime I have gotten scratches in my sinks I used SOS pads in a circular fashion.  After a lot of elbow grease all have gone away.  Not sure how bad your scratches are though.